# Symfony 2 controller gets json data but db query don't get values

Tags: symfony

I have a controller to get json data and select a value from database, my problem is that, I get de json data but when I try to select the database value I always get `[]` as result.

Here is my controller code.

```
public function stockAction(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    .
    .
    .
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

        $data = $request->getContent();
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Objeto');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.reffabrica = :code')
            ->setParameter('code', $data)
            ->getQuery();

        $resultado = $query->getResult();

        return new JsonResponse(json_encode($resultado));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Solved using this code:

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

        $data = $request->getContent();

        $code = "'" . $data . "'";

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Objeto');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.reffabrica = ' . $code)
            ->getQuery();

        $resultado = $query->getArrayResult();

        return new JsonResponse($resultado);
    }
```

Comment: what does `$data` contains ...?

Comment: $data contains a string

Comment: So, reffabrica column in your table contains json data? What the type of reffabrica column? What kind of data are stored there?

Comment: The value of $data is "136kf47dsa" is an example of barcode. reffabrica column in my table contains string data. I want to get from database table all column values when the reffabrica = "136kf47dsa".

Comment: So run the query in phpmyadmin and check if someone is returned, you can get the sql with: `$query->getSQL()`

Comment: The query in phpmyadmin works and returns the right value, but if i run `$query->getSQL()` returns:

`SELECT ... FROM objeto o0_ WHERE o0_.reffabrica = ?`

Answer (score 0):

You should dump $resultado to be sure. In any case this line is wrong

```
return new JsonResponse(json_encode($resultado));
```

json_encode parameter must be an array:

```
return new JsonResponse($resultado);
```

Comment: Now my query gets the parameter, i changed the createquerybuilder where format.
`$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->where('p.reffabrica = ' . $codi)
                ->getQuery();`

Now the query has the right format but the var $resultado gets an empty object. Any one knows where is the problem?